# mock a bean locally, in the same class

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I've a `TestClass` with two Tests `foo()` and `bar()`, `foo` uses the original bean `serviceObject`, while `bar` uses a mockedBean: so always one test fails. is there any way to mock my bean only for `bar()`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
pubic class TestClass{
    
    @MockBean
    private ServiceObject serviceObject;

    @Test
    public void foo(){
    //do smt test with non mocked bean serviceObject
    }
    
    @Test
    public void bar(){
    //do smt with mockedBean
    }
}
```

Comment: They are different tests and should be treated as such. Write 2 different test classes (one is probably an integration test, the other a simpler unit test).

Answer (score 1):

I would split up the tests into two different classes, as they obviously test something completely different.

One (`foo()`) probably tests the behaviour of the `ServiceBean` implementation, the other (`bar()`) tests something that uses a `ServiceBean` instance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can create one instance with `@Autowired` annotation in class scope and mock it in method scope.

Comment: mock(ServiceObject .class);

Comment: or use just local obj in method scope

Answer (score 0):

Just use the object that you need to use in any given test.
Here is some example code:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TestClass {
    @MockBean
    private ServiceObject mockServiceObject;

    
    @Test
    public void foo(){
        ServiceObject blam = new ServiceObject();
        
        // Use blam in this test
        // do something test with non mocked bean serviceObject
    }
    
    @Test
    public void bar(){
        // do something with mockedBean
        // use mockServiceObject in this test
    }
}
```